# Wildfly leave Two Orphaned File Descriptors after uploading a file

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, wildfly

I'm running Wildfly version 14 and version 18 (on different machines) and Primefaces.  Whenever I upload a file, I get 2 orphaned fds.  I've doubled checked my code and all resources are closed.  I didn't have any problem running Wildfly 11, btw.  I also use lsof to make sure that the opened files belong to Wildfly, and they are.  Eventually, I get the Too Many Open Files error.

```
ls -alFtr /proc/30724/fd|grep elete
lr-x------ 1 ora ora 64 Apr  3 09:36 594 -> /PATH_TO/undertow1607766259253292434upload (deleted)
lr-x------ 1 ora ora 64 Apr  3 09:40 591 -> /PATH_TO/undertow1607766259253292434upload (deleted)
```

Googling the problem gave me several RedHat links, but I can't find any solution to my problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: Neve upload files to your webapp folder... Upload them to a temp location

Comment: I don't.  I uploaded to a different directory..  What you see there is not my uploaded file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if you are using PF 7.X this was a bug and fixed in PF8.0.

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5408

Comment: Thanks so much!  I will upgrade to PF8 and report back.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks again.